# How to refer to files from other directories while running a docker image?

Tags: r, docker, installation, containers, singularity-container

I tried to run a program [SAIGE-GENE](https://github.com/weizhouUMICH/SAIGE/wiki/Genetic-association-tests-using-SAIGE) using docker image. After using docker pull with `docker pull wzhou88/saige:0.43.2` I was able to make it run.

[image]

However, I can't locate the input files using docker exec. My files are on the desktop and I have cd-ed into this directory already. The command I used is as follows:

```
docker exec -w /Users/garyzhubc/Desktop d7501bd45226 /usr/local/bin/step2_SPAtests.R \
  --bgenFile=ukb_imp_chr1_v3_pruned_reduced.bgen \
  --bgenFileIndex=ukb_imp_chr1_v3_pruned_reduced.bgen.bgi \
  --sampleFile=ukb_imp_chr1_v3_pruned_reduced.sample \
  --chrom=1 \
  --minMAF=0 \
  --minMAC=0.5 \
  --maxMAFforGroupTest=0.01 \
  --GMMATmodelFile=./output/example_quantitative.rda \
  --varianceRatioFile=./output/example_quantitative_cate.varianceRatio.txt \
  --SAIGEOutputFile=./output/example_quantitative.SAIGE.gene.txt \
  --numLinesOutput=1 \
  --groupFile=group_file.tsv \
  --sparseSigmaFile=./output/example_quantitative_cate.varianceRatio.txt_relatednessCutoff_0.125_2000_randomMarkersUsed.sparseSigma.mtx \
  --IsSingleVarinGroupTest=TRUE \
  --LOCO=FALSE
```

as this doesn't work since it still cannot locate the file

```
OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:370: starting container process caused: chdir to cwd ("/Users/garyzhubc/Desktop") set in config.json failed: no such file or directory: unknown
```

Comment: You need to either build your own image `FROM wzhou88/saige:0.43.2` and `COPY` https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy your files into the image, or mount https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#mount-volume--v---read-only your files when you run the container

Comment: @Dornaut Thanks. How to moon these files in this case?